# EditView внутри TableRow, у которого есть drawable бэкграунд, ломает верстку при фокусе. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android, xml, table, android-drawable

Программно создаю табличку из двух колонок:

```
    final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
    row.setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);
    row.setBackground(row_background);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    row.addView(ViewUtils.getDefaultTextView(context, "Оценка критерия"));

    EditText value = new EditText(context);
    value.setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);
    value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    value.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(0, 100)});
    value.setTextSize(12);
    value.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    value.setHint("Введите число от 0 до 100");

    row.addView(value);

row_background это xml

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#E7E7E7" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

где в зависимоcти от начало или середина или конец таблицы меняется скругление углов.

когда открывается экран - визуально выглядит все обычно, за исключением того, что надпись "Оценка критерия" прижимается к низу нижней черты.При клике на editview же вообще у верхнего ряда меняется верстка, визуально будто бы уменьшаясь по высоте.

После клика выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это все побороть? Я пробовал переписать на LineLayout - не помогает, точно такая же ситуация, будто бы меняются размеры после клика или после добавления вьюхи и накладываемый на row бэкграунд не правильно отрабатывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему создав для каждой строки макет в xml, после чего добавляю row в таблицу через механизм инфлэта